# Latest changes in Documentation Center

Tags: documentation

I used to be able to copy code selectively in the Wolfram Documentation Center.  Clicking on every piece of code used to generate a pop up in the format of InputForm (I think?). I really liked it because I could copy only those parts that I wanted. However, it suddenly changed (maybe in the last week or so). Right now, one of these two situations happen:

1. A new functionality has been enabled that copies the whole code to
   the clipboard when you click on it. It doesn't let you select which
   parts to copy. It doesn't even ask if you want to copy  or not, it
   just does it on a single click.
2. Everything gets distorted as
   shown in the following image:

[image]

I want to know if others are experinceing the same thing. Also, can you think of any tricks to copy selectively? I've already tried Chrome, FireFox, Internet Explorer!!!, and an Andriod browser.

Comment: I do like the change, in that it gets rid of popups (I hate popups). I also don't experience the web page distortion you see (on Win7-64 using the latest Firefox). The only reason I do not like the change is the fact that the popup used to contain a direct link to the code, somewhat like an anchor link, which was immensely useful to link to a specific part of the documentation, e.g. on this site. I don't know how to recover that in the new format, but I'd love to!

Comment: @MarcoB I didn't even think of that linking thing. It's just that flexibility has been reduced.